# Why background-color doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set background-color for my footer, but it doesn't really change the background color.
This is what I have done so far.

In my code: I have wrapped the footer by body tag. That means the footer is inside the body tag.

.HTML:

```
<footer>
<div id="footer_box">

                <p id="footer_text_left">

                © 7 seas<br />                                          

                En del av 7seas Money Transfer KB<br />                 
                F-skatt registrerat  <br />                                         
                Org, Nr: <br />   

                SEB Företagskonto: <br />
                BG: 

                </p>

                <p id="footer_text_middle">
                Besökadress:<br /> 
                218 41 Bunkeflostrand<br /> 
                Malmö, Sweden <br />  


                Web:

                </p>

            <p id="footer_text_right">


                Tel: <br />
                 Mob: <br />
                 e-Mail:

                </p>

</div>

        </footer>
```

.CSS:

```
#footer_box{
    border-top:2px solid #009933;

     background-color:green;

    }



    #footer_text_middle, #footer_text_right{

    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Euphemia;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    padding-bottom:15px;


    }
    #footer_text_left{
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Euphemia;
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    margin-left: 120px;

    padding-bottom:15px;
    }
```

Comment: In any case, a duplicate of [container div not applyin background-color to the two floating divs inside it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048102/container-div-not-applyin-background-color-to-the-two-floating-divs-inside-it)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/smenr5nq/11/ i think you want this

Comment: My apology: Ther was a wrong jS fiddle link. I removed it now. However, pbaldauf's answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` in your css:

```
#footer_box{
    overflow: auto;
    border-top:2px solid #009933;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgvbmuda/).

Comment: it works, 100%. though I put a wrong link in js fiddle. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a clearfix class on your footer_box element:

```
<div id="footer_box" class="clearfix">
```

And add this in css:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Replace the "." with " ", there is no need to pollute it with anything else than whitespace. Removes the need for line-height as well. :)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't noticed it, I just took the first clearfix class I found on google. :)

Comment: `content: " "`, not `content: ""` since the latter effectively doesn't do anything. And I wouldn't be so bold as to use `.clearfix{display: inline-block;}` since you can use this for several other block levels as well, like `block`, `table` and `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the green color background to the `#footer_text_left`, `#footer_text_middle`, and `#footer_text_right` `<p>` tags.

```css
#footer_box, #footer_text_left, #footer_text_middle, #footer_text_right{
    border-top:2px solid #009933;

     background-color:green;

    }



    #footer_text_middle, #footer_text_right{

    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Euphemia;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    padding-bottom:15px;


    }
    #footer_text_left{
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Euphemia;
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    margin-left: 120px;

    padding-bottom:15px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="footer_box">

                <p id="footer_text_left">

                © 7 seas<br />                                          

                En del av 7seas Money Transfer KB<br />                 
                F-skatt registrerat  <br />                                         
                Org, Nr: <br />   

                SEB Företagskonto: <br />
                BG: 

                </p>

                <p id="footer_text_middle">
                Besökadress:<br /> 
                218 41 Bunkeflostrand<br /> 
                Malmö, Sweden <br />  


                Web:

                </p>

            <p id="footer_text_right">


                Tel: <br />
                 Mob: <br />
                 e-Mail:

                </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding: `overflow:auto;` should do the trick

Not Related to your question, the use of `<br/>` is a bit frowned upon. it would be better if EACH sentence is stored into a `<p>` and given a class with a `margin-bottom` for example.

Just a thought though

Comment: i edited my post, there was a wrong link. however, pbaldauf's answer helped me. and you gave a same suggestion thoug.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see the update when I posted it :) pbaldauf's answer is the same about the `overflow`, I'm talking about the `<br/>`. They are not used much, better if you style a margin between each line manually by enclosing each sentence in a `<p>` `<br/>` has certain browser compatible issues,[CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br)